Rebuild skip all project in Visual Studio 2022
I do not understand why Visual Studio skips all the projects to do rebuild of the solution.
The output console only shows that the projects were skipped.
I have tried deleting the bin, obj and .vs folders, but that did not work.
I have tried to restart the computer - but that also did not work.
Include call a team mate, and in Visual Studio of my team mate, the rebuild works fine. This only occurs in my Visual Studio.
output rebuild
Has anyone had this error?
Where I can see more information about the skipped projects and the reason for skipping them?

Use Build > Configuration Manager.

Regarding the issue of projects being skipped when building, I recommend that you right-click on the solution, select "Properties", and then select "Configuration Properties". Here you can select the projects to build.
In addition, here is a post with similar issues to yours, you can refer to the other suggestions there:
How to determine why visual studio might be skipping projects when building a solution

In  the post provide by @cody liang I found the solution: Remove the project of the solution , and after, add existing projects one by one
